# Calling Google Places/Nearby API from inside an iOS App

Tags: ios, json, ionic-framework, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to call the Google Places API to return a list of restaurants near me. When I call this from a browser it works fine. However, when I call this from inside an iOS App I built using Ionic Framework, it fails with a data NULL, status 0 error.

I researched quite a bit, figured out this was a CORS issue. I looked up Google documentation on how to issue GET requests for iOS App. I used my app's bundle id to create a key and client ID for my app. Using the steps here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#overview, I obtained an access_token, which I used as a query parameter just like the docs mentioned. Nothing works. What is going wrong?

URL that works on browser: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=MyServerApplicationsKey&location=33.85463,-84.35870&rankby=distance&types=restaurant

URL that fails from IOS App: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=MyiOSApplicationsKey&location=33.85463,-84.35870&rankby=distance&types=restaurant&access_token=MyToken

@plexer
I use the server key to call the URL from the browser. That works, as mentioned. From the App if I use this key, I get the following error:
 {"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"sameUrlThatWorksOnBrowser","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}

Comment: are you using livereload on device?

Comment: Yes, I am. How is that related though?

Comment: So, I figured out that this has to do with the "list of allowed IPs" in the Key for Server Applications section.. This is painful though, as I need to specify a list of all IPs that the request will be coming from! Any way to make this work for any IP address?

Comment: you can set * and allow all the IPs. I haven't implemented that, but I think its possible.

Comment: * doesn't actually work.. Can someone tell me how to include incoming traffic from ANY ip address, coz at the moment, my app works only from machines I know the ip address of..

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places API uses a Public API Access key, rather than oAuth. The good news is that these are a lot simpler to get started with.

Follow the instructions under the Authentication section on [this page](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro) to create a new **Public API access key**, then include that key in the &key parameter for your application.

After clicking the "Create new Key" button, select "Server key". That's a bit weird, since you are calling the API from iOS, but it will work.

Comment: Hi plexer, I have edited my question. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ajinkya, i haven't tried  whether it helps. As Ionic supports angular , this directive helps u http://angular-js.in/google-places-autocomplete/